# How to cut (azure_iot_sdk_c) to facilitate porting to embedded Linux platform

Tags: c, iot, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

I have successfully compiled (azure_iot_sdk_c) on Linux and successfully run this demo (iothub_ll_c2d_sample). Now, I want to extract the source code related to this demo to facilitate the migration to the embedded Linux platform. What should I do? The source code provided by Microsoft contains a lot of code unrelated to the Linux platform in order to be compatible with more platforms.

I tried to take out the source code in the sdk, delete the code of other platforms, and judge whether the platform is related by the file name, but it could not be compiled. I want to know what files are required for this demo (iothub_ll_c2d_sample) to run normally. I want to take them out and compile them separately, so that they can be ported to the embedded Linux platform.

Comment: Hi @coalboss, have you looked into this resource [Set up a linux development environmet](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/blob/main/doc/devbox_setup.md#set-up-a-linux-development-environment) that explains how to set up a development environment for the C SDK on Ubuntu. Here is another resource [Learn Azure IoT device SDK for C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-device-sdk-c-intro) that provides you more detailed explanation on how to use and build solutions using C SDK. I recommend reading the resources to get more understanding

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the code sample file and compile it independently by importing the required header files for the code in iothub_ll_c2d_sample.c

Even though the code lists only six external reference files, some of the header files have internal dependencies. By back tracing, I found eighteen header files that are referenced by them. You would have to provide a local reference to all these files to make the code compile successfully. Please find the below image referring all the header files the program needs to compile.

[image]

You can get the header files from the below URLs

1. https://github.com/Azure/azure-c-shared-utility/blob/master/inc/azure_c_shared_utility/map.h
2. https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-arduino-utility/blob/master/src/azure_c_shared_utility/azure_macro_utils/macro_utils.h
3. https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/blob/main/iothub_client/inc/iothub_device_client_ll.h
4. https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-arduino-utility/blob/master/src/azure_c_shared_utility/azure_macro_utils/macro_utils_generated.h
5. https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/blob/main/iothub_client/inc/iothub.h
6. https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/blob/main/iothub_client/inc/iothub_transport_ll.h
7. https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/blob/main/iothub_client/inc/iothub_client_core_ll.h
8. https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/blob/main/iothub_client/inc/iothub_client_core_common.h
9. https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/blob/main/iothub_client/inc/iothub_message.h
10. https://github.com/Azure/azure-c-shared-utility/blob/master/inc/azure_c_shared_utility/strings.h
11. https://github.com/Azure/azure-c-shared-utility/blob/master/inc/azure_c_shared_utility/const_defines.h
12. https://github.com/Azure/azure-c-shared-utility/blob/master/inc/azure_c_shared_utility/strings_types.h
13. https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/blob/main/iothub_client/inc/iothubtransportmqtt.h
14. https://github.com/Azure/azure-c-shared-utility/blob/master/inc/azure_c_shared_utility/shared_util_options.h
15. https://github.com/Azure/azure-c-shared-utility/blob/master/inc/azure_c_shared_utility/crt_abstractions.h
16. https://github.com/Azure/azure-c-shared-utility/blob/master/inc/azure_c_shared_utility/threadapi.h
17. https://github.com/Azure/umock-c/blob/master/inc/umock_c/umock_c_prod.h
18. https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/blob/main/iothub_client/inc/iothub_client_options.h

Note that since I have the files under the same directory, I will no longer need to provide a relative path while referencing the header files in the program. I can directly access them as below

[image]

The same goes with the header files. I can directly refer the dependent header files without providing any relative path. Please find the below image of the iothub.h header file which refernces umock_c_prod.h file and notice there is no relative path.

[image]

If you decide to place the header files under a different directory, make sure to provide a relative path for the code to compile.